# How to use wildcards in IVY: <artifacts pattern="..."/>

Tags: ivy

I want to publish my artifacts with ivy but my build path is dynamic and not static since it contains the version TAG i.e.: "build_02.14Test3".

This is from my build.xml:

```
<target name="go" depends="install-ivy" 
            description="--> create and publish">
            <property environment="env"/>   
            <fail unless="env.PUBREVISION" message="no publish revision set!"/>
        <ivy:resolve/>  
        <ivy:publish resolver="components" pubrevision="${env.PUBREVISION}">
            <artifacts pattern="../Java/build_*/Release/[artifact].[ext]"/>
        </ivy:publish>
    </target>
```

**The whole build.xml file:**

```
<!--
   Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
   or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
   distributed with this work for additional information
   regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
   to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
   "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
   with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
   software distributed under the License is distributed on an
   "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
   KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
   specific language governing permissions and limitations
   under the License.    
-->
<project name="build-ivy" default="go" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">
    <!-- 

        More information can be found at http://ant.apache.org/ivy/
        -->

    <!-- here is the version of ivy we will use. change this property to try a newer 
         version if you want -->
    <property name="ivy.install.version" value="2.4.0" />
    <property name="ivy.jar.dir" value="${basedir}/ivy" />
    <property name="ivy.jar.file" value="${ivy.jar.dir}/ivy.jar" />

    <property name="build.dir" value="build" />
    <property name="src.dir" value="src" />


    <target name="download-ivy" unless="skip.download">
        <mkdir dir="${ivy.jar.dir}"/>
        <!-- download Ivy from artifactory so that it can be used even without any special installation -->
        <echo message="installing ivy..."/>
        <get src="https://artifactory.company.com/artifactory/virtual-maven/org/apache/ivy/ivy/${ivy.install.version}/ivy-${ivy.install.version}.jar"
             dest="${ivy.jar.file}" usetimestamp="true" username="svcbuild" password="**********************"/>
    </target>

    <!-- ================================= 
          target: install-ivy         
            this target is not necessary if you put ivy.jar in your ant lib directory
            if you already have ivy in your ant lib, you can simply remove this
            target and the dependency the 'go' target has on it
         ================================= -->
    <target name="install-ivy" depends="download-ivy" description="--> install ivy">
        <!-- try to load ivy here from local ivy dir, in case the user has not already dropped
              it into ant's lib dir (note that the latter copy will always take precedence).
              We will not fail as long as local lib dir exists (it may be empty) and
              ivy is in at least one of ant's lib dir or the local lib dir. -->
        <path id="ivy.lib.path">
            <fileset dir="${ivy.jar.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>
        </path>
        <taskdef resource="org/apache/ivy/ant/antlib.xml"
                  uri="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant" classpathref="ivy.lib.path"/>
    </target>    

    <!-- ================================= 
          target: go
                    Go ivy, go!
         ================================= -->
   <target name="go" depends="install-ivy" 
            description="--> create and publish">
            <property environment="env"/>   
            <fail unless="env.PUBREVISION" message="no publish revision set!"/>
        <ivy:resolve/>  
        <ivy:publish resolver="components" pubrevision="${env.PUBREVISION}">
            <artifacts pattern="../Java/build_*/Release/[artifact].[ext]"/>
        </ivy:publish>
    </target>


    <!-- ================================= 
          target: clean              
         ================================= -->
    <target name="clean" description="--> clean the project">
        <delete includeemptydirs="true" quiet="true">
            <fileset dir="${src.dir}" />
            <fileset dir="${build.dir}" />
        </delete>
    </target>

    <!-- ================================= 
          target: clean-ivy              
         ================================= -->
    <target name="clean-ivy" description="--> clean the ivy installation">
        <delete dir="${ivy.jar.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <!-- ================================= 
          target: clean-cache              
         ================================= -->
    <target name="clean-cache" depends="install-ivy" 
            description="--> clean the ivy cache">
        <ivy:cleancache />
    </target>
</project>
```

Basically all I wanna know is why my wildcard "*" is not working and how to fix it.

When running my pipeline I run into the issue that the wildcards are not recogniced:

```
[ivy:publish] :: delivering :: COMPANY#some.product;working@BUILD_PC :: 02.14Test11 :: integration :: Fri Feb 09 09:13:36 CET 2018
[ivy:publish]   options = status=integration pubdate=Fri Feb 09 09:13:36 CET 2018 validate=true resolveDynamicRevisions=true merge=true resolveId=null pubBranch=null
[ivy:publish]   delivering ivy file to D:\gr\builds\3d9e5594\0\plast\products\some.product\Java\build_*\Release\ivy.xml

BUILD FAILED
D:\gr\builds\3d9e5594\0\plast\products\some.product\ivy\build.xml:70: COMPANY#some.product;working@BUILD_PC: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\gr\builds\3d9e5594\0\plast\products\some.product\Java\build_*\Release\ivy.xml (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:212)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:165)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.parser.xml.XmlModuleDescriptorUpdater.update(XmlModuleDescriptorUpdater.java:135)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.deliver.DeliverEngine.deliver(DeliverEngine.java:207)
    at org.apache.ivy.Ivy.deliver(Ivy.java:607)
    at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyDeliver.doExecute(IvyDeliver.java:420)
    at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyTask.execute(IvyTask.java:271)
    at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyPublish.doExecute(IvyPublish.java:308)
    at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyTask.execute(IvyTask.java:271)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1376)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:857)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:236)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:287)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:113)
```

**Ivy.xml as requested** (Note I replaced company and product names!) :

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="MyOrganisation" module="Organisation.product" />
    <publications>

<artifact name="Data1" ext="cab" type="binaries" />
<artifact name="Organisation product" ext="msi" type="binaries" />
<artifact name="setup" ext="exe" type="binaries" />
<artifact name="splash" ext="bmp" type="binaries" />
<artifact name="Java/jre-8u131-windows-i586" ext="exe" type="binaries" />
<artifact name="ProdA RemTool/Data1" ext="cab" type="binaries" />
<artifact name="ProdA RemTool/ProdA RemTool 01.36" ext="msi" type="binaries" />
<artifact name="ProdA RemTool/setup" ext="exe" type="binaries" />
<artifact name="ProdA RemTool/splash" ext="png" type="binaries" />
<artifact name="ProdA RemTool/viewsimba.splash" ext="bmp" type="binaries" />

 </publications>

</ivy-module>
```

Comment: Could you please edit the question and add the ivy.xml that you're publishing?

Comment: Added ivy.xml  .

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to see `revision` in the ivy.xml. Where does this version tag come from? I mean based on what you know that the folder name is going to be that `build_*` ? Maybe this is the revision?

Comment: Hey man, thanks for helping out. With revision we are talking about the build TAG right? Basically with my ".gitlab-ci.yml" file I'm passing the "revision" to a batch file called "createivy.bat" => "createivy %CI_COMMIT_TAG%". "createivy.bat" then basically just executes ANT on the build.xml file which I posted at the top.

Comment: No problem :) Yes, build tag. Well, tha's a git hash then, so it wouldn't be good to use it for revision (in the ivy context)

Comment: Okay, so yes the build tag is part of the foldername. If my Tag is "02.12Test4" the build result folder will be called "build_02.12Test4". I'd rather not change this behavior and keep the tag in the folder names but I just can't get the wildcard to work! (Also I put my whole build.xml in the post, maybe it helps) It's either a GIT hash or a TAG. If it's a git hash ( a regular commit) I don't care but if it is TAGged I care. Hope this makes sense :)

Comment: Well, I'm sure I missed something... :) First the obvious question - can't you simply pass the folder name to build.xml? I mean just run ant with -D and give a parameter and use that parameter as a property within build.xml and use that in `ivy:publish` like so <artifacts pattern="../Java/${myPassedParam}/Release/[artifact].[ext]"/>

Comment: Okay, so I fixed it. This is the correct line: <artifacts pattern="../Java/build_${env.PUBREVISION}/Release/[artifact].[ext]"/> . The ${env.PUBREVISION}/ parameter contains exactly my TAG and as a result the correct build path:  Thank you all for trying to help me out. It's always tricky to pickup something new :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164952/discussion-between-cantsleepnow-and-markus).

Comment: I have a similar issue. I have a resolver from a local installation of a tool. The path to the local installation depends on where the user has chosen to install it, so I need wildcards to specify some of the typical potential paths. I'm using Ivy as a stand-alone jar by invoking `java -jar ivy-2.4.0.jar` but it appears to ignore any custom params sent  with `-D`. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to my problem was to fix the build path like this:

```
<artifacts pattern="../Java/build_${env.PUBREVISION}/Release/[artifact].[ext]"/>
```

since `${env.PUBREVISION}/` contains the TAG which is my build folder :)